# How to Validate checkbox maximum check/select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to validate for maximum checked by user to 3. If user check more than 3, i want to show to user maximum available is 3 OR I want to disable others checkbox before submit form with javascript or jquery

```
<div class="seatplan">
  <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `name='a[1]'` and look in the array for the checked boxes

Comment: What have you tried so far and why is `php`tagged in this? With some research I think you will find limiting checkbox selection has been answered many times.

Comment: i do cinema plan with php. not sure limiting checkbox with php..@NewToJS

Answer (score 2):

Please check out the below code. Hope it helps:

```js
$('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  var checked = $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  console.log(checked);

  if (checked >= 3) {
    $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seatplan">
  <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
</div>
```

Basically I'm listening to the `change` event of each checkbox and then based on the length of the checked items, I disable/enable the rest of the checkboxes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077991 could you answer me this one too.. @31ply

Comment: @MaungYeHtunZaw -- I've tried to answer your other question as well. Please accept the answers if those helped you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go without jQuery you could do:

```js
const seatplan = document.querySelector('.seatplan');

seatplan.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const checked = seatplan.querySelectorAll('input:checked');
    const unchecked = seatplan.querySelectorAll('input:not(:checked)');
    if (checked.length >= 3) {
        unchecked.forEach(el => el.setAttribute('disabled', true));
    } else {
        unchecked.forEach(el => el.removeAttribute('disabled'));
    }
});
```

```css
.seatplan > input{
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.seatplan > input:disabled{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="seatplan">
    <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can also show message using another div or label field in the screen as shown below

<

```
!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->enter code here`

    $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
      var checked = $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
      console.log(checked);

      if (checked >= 3) {
$("diverror").show();
$("diverror").html("A maximum of only 3 check boxes can be checked")
        $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
$("diverror").hide();
        $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
      }
    })

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="seatplan">
      <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
    </div>
<div id="diverror"></div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="seatplan">
  <p class="limit">0 / 3</p>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
</div>

$('.seatplan input').on('click', function() {
  $('.limit').text(`${$('.seatplan input:checked').length} / 3`);
  $('.seatplan input').prop('disabled', '');

  if ($('.seatplan input:checked').length >= 3) {
    $('.seatplan input:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sjmfxtag/

This doesn't require any variables. It also gives the user a visual of the limit.

Answer (score 0):

var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

if(checked>3)

{

alert('not valid');

return false;

}

else
{

alert('valid');

return true;

}