# How to show checked checkbox infomation outside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing for cinema seating plan with php. I want to show to users what seat they selected and what price must pay in ticketinfo div with jquery on seat select and remove info when they uncheck..

```
    <div class="seatplan">
      <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
    </div>
    <div class="ticketinfo">
        seat no A1   200
        seat no A3   200
       -------------------
        Total Amount 400
    </div>
```

Comment: and what have you tried? I can certainly see that is no javascript. Please, create a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you want to do something like this?

```js
$(document).on('change',':checkbox', function() {
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $('.ticketinfo > ul > li:eq(0)').before('<li rel="' + $(this).attr('name') + '">seat no ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' - ' + parseInt($(this).val()) + '</li>');
     $('.ticketinfo > ul > li > span').html(parseInt($('.ticketinfo > ul > li > span').text()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
   } else {
     $('[rel="' +  $(this).attr('name') + '"]').remove();
     $('.ticketinfo > ul > li > span').html(parseInt($('.ticketinfo > ul > li > span').text()) - parseInt($(this).val()));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seatplan">
      <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
      <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
    </div>
    <div class="ticketinfo">
    <ul>
        <li>Total Amount <span>0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `change` event of the checkboxes and create your result by looping over the checked elements.

```js
$('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  var result = [];
  var total = 0;

  $('.seatplan input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    result.push(`
      <tr>
        <td>${$(this).attr('name')}</td>
        <td>${$(this).attr('value')}</td>
      </tr>
    `);

    total += parseInt($(this).attr('value'), 10);
  });

  result.push(`
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>${total}</td>
      </tr>
    `);
  $('.ticketinfo tbody').html(result.join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seatplan">
  <input type='checkbox' name='A1' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A2' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A3' value='300'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A4' value='200'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300'>
</div>
<table class="ticketinfo">
  <thead>
    <th>Seat No.</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've changed the result section from `div` to `table` since it will be quite difficult to show row-column wise data in a `div` tag.

Comment: above code is working on disable checkbox, how do i check it...? @31piy

Comment: <input type='checkbox' name='A5' value='300' disabled> checkbox click also show price infomation

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ticket Booking</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.book-chk').change(onSeatChengeEvt);
});
function onSeatChengeEvt(){
    var total=0, infoHtml='', selItems=$('.book-chk:checked'), i, selLen=selItems.length;
    for(i=0; i<selLen; i++){
        infoHtml += 'seat no '+selItems[i].name+' &nbsp; &nbsp; '+selItems[i].value+'<br />';
        total += Number(selItems[i].value);
    }
    infoHtml += '------------------------<br>Total Amount '+total;
    $('#ticketInfo').html(infoHtml);
}
</head>
<body>
<div class="seatplan">
  <label><input type='checkbox' class="book-chk" name='A1' value='200' autocomplete="off"> A1</label><br>
  <label><input type='checkbox' class="book-chk" name='A2' value='200' autocomplete="off"> A2</label><br>
  <label><input type='checkbox' class="book-chk" name='A3' value='300' autocomplete="off"> A3</label><br>
  <label><input type='checkbox' class="book-chk" name='A4' value='200' autocomplete="off"> A4</label><br>
  <label><input type='checkbox' class="book-chk" name='A5' value='300' autocomplete="off"> A5</label><br>
</div>
<div class="ticketinfo" id="ticketInfo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```